# How to prevent LastPass from displaying icon inside lightning-input

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput

Based on [this LastPass guidance](https://support.lastpass.com/help/how-do-i-prevent-fields-from-being-filled-automatically) I've tried `data-lpignore` and `data-lpignore="true"`, per this markup:

```
  <lightning-input
        if:true={colmod.showme}
        required={colmod.required}
        type={colmod.type}                    
        data-api={colmod.fieldName}
        label={colmod.label}
        readonly={colmod.readonlyeditor}
        onchange={onInputChange}
        variant="label-inline"
        data-lpignore="true"
    ></lightning-input>
```

But I still get results that look like this:

[image: example screenshot of lightnin-input form fields with LastPass icon]

FWIW - I don't see the `data-` items in the rendered DOM, so I suppose it's all in the shadows - anyone else find a successful solution to this? Not interested in requiring users to modify/disable LastPass yet.

Answer (score 2):

After re-reading the LastPass guidance, I realized I had not done this:

> In your LastPass browser extension preferences (Advanced settings), enable the Respect AutoComplete=off setting, which will allow websites to disable the autofill feature.

Once I did, it started working as advertised. Yes, right after I posted this question

Comment: This is what I needed, thank you!  Even better in my case was to also enable the setting:

"Don't overwrite fields that are already filled"

In General > Form Fill

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, if you want to hide it on specific form of specific input, you can use CSS.
Something like :

```
 svg[data-lastpass-icon=true]{
    visibility:none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS snippet helped me where `autocomplete` and `data-lpignore` did not work, out of box:

```css
div[data-lastpass-icon-root] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should find other to replace lasspass, because
It may be make wrong data be cause autofill in any Form.
This problem still along time, but lasspass not fix it!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. This site _thrives_ on details. While a "frame challenge" like this can make for a good answer, you generally need to go into extra detail about why the current solution isn't appropriate, present a better choice, and explain why this other choice _is_ appropriate. I don't feel that this answer rises to meet those criteria.